# How to convert a string to lower or upper case in Ruby

Tags: ruby, string, uppercase, lowercase

How do I take a string and convert it to lower or upper case in Ruby?

Answer (score 1778, accepted):

Ruby has a few methods for changing the case of strings. To convert to lowercase, use `downcase`:

```
"hello James!".downcase    #=> "hello james!"
```

Similarly, `upcase` capitalizes every letter and `capitalize` capitalizes the first letter of the string but lowercases the rest:

```
"hello James!".upcase      #=> "HELLO JAMES!"
"hello James!".capitalize  #=> "Hello james!"
"hello James!".titleize    #=> "Hello James!" (Rails/ActiveSupport only)
```

If you want to modify a string in place, you can add an exclamation point to any of those methods:

```
string = "hello James!"
string.downcase!
string   #=> "hello james!"
```

Refer to the [documentation for String](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/String.html) for more information.

Comment: Watch out! looks to me like using the bang "!"  will return nil if there's no capital letter.   so  str = "this".downcase!  returns str = nil

Comment: Oftentimes, "bang methods" return `nil`; you should use them if you want to change an object in place, not if you want to store the value in another variable.

Comment: but it'is a problem in "i" char if you are using utf-8. For instance, string = FEN BİLİMLERİ. string.capitalize must be "Fen bİlİmlerİ" or it could be changed because of css font style choice.

Comment: `'coração'.upcase` produces `'CORAçãO'`. It may be advised to use some gem like “unicode_utils“, “activesupport“ or “Unicode”.

Answer (score 128):

You can find out all the methods available on a String by opening irb and running:

```
"MyString".methods.sort
```

And for a list of the methods available for strings in particular:

```
"MyString".own_methods.sort
```

I use this to find out new and interesting things about objects which I might not otherwise have known existed.

Comment: The only problem with this answer is that #own_methods doesn't appear to exist. Is it from an Irb extension?

Comment: Hi - I thought I was learning something new with the #own_methods then, but it doesn't exist for me either. However, I usually go:
("MyString".methods - Object.merhods).sort

Comment: Ditto. @mlambie might have something like [this monkey patch](http://www.wikyblog.com/AmanKing/A_Ruby_object%27s_own_methods) set up somewhere.

Comment: Very similar to the patch @fakeleft referenced, and I have it in my .irbrc file.

I monkey patch Object and create #own_methds with this:

  (obj.methods - obj.class.superclass.instance_methods).sort

Comment: What's the difference between 'all the methods available on a String' and 'the methods available for strings in particular' ? They seem synonymous. Of course it doesn't particular matter since own_methods seems to be some extension I don't have, but I still am curious.

Comment: @Laser The methods for String in particular are the ones defined in the String class itself. The methods available on a String include the ones defined in its superclass(es).

Comment: @QPaysTaxes Got it, thanks. Any idea why own_methods doesn't exist for me in irb ruby 2.1.4? Are there no methods by default in the String class, so it would just be if I manually had added some? And if I wanted to, do you know where I'd find basic ruby classes, like String, in a rails app? Thanks

Comment: @Laser Well, according to [fakeleft's comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1020568/how-to-convert-a-string-to-lower-or-upper-case-in-ruby/1021299?noredirect=1#comment18832728_1021299), it's possible a monkey patch or something. It's not a real extension. I have no idea where you'd find the definitions in a Rails installation; presumably in the same place as a Ruby one. The problem is that it might be in C, so unless you can read C you wouldn't be able to read the source file.

Comment: Use [`String.public_instance_methods(false)`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.5/Module.html#method-i-public_instance_methods) to find all public instance methods specifically defined by `String`.

Comment: Or you can look for official documentation, all methods which belong to any class are already over there. :)

Answer (score 41):

Like @endeR mentioned, if internationalization is a concern, the unicode_utils gem is more than adequate.

```
$ gem install unicode_utils
$ irb
> require 'unicode_utils'
=> true
> UnicodeUtils.downcase("FEN BİLİMLERİ", :tr)
=> "fen bilimleri"
```

---

String manipulations  in Ruby 2.4 are now unicode-sensitive.

Answer (score 24):

The ruby `downcase` method returns a string with its uppercase letters replaced by lowercase letters.

```
"string".downcase
```

https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/String.html#method-i-downcase

Comment: ruby conversions here: http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Ruby_String_Conversions

Comment: While technically this does help answer the question, it really should be more illuminating. Show the result perhaps? Maybe a link to the documentation?

Answer (score 15):

... and the uppercase is:

```
"Awesome String".upcase
=> "AWESOME STRING"
```

Answer (score 14):

The  Rails Active Support gem provides `upcase`, `downcase`, `swapcase`,`capitalize`, etc. methods with internationalization support:

```
gem install activesupport
irb -ractive_support/core_ext/string
"STRING  ÁÂÃÀÇÉÊÍÓÔÕÚ".mb_chars.downcase.to_s
 => "string  áâãàçéêíóôõú"
"string  áâãàçéêíóôõú".mb_chars.upcase.to_s
=> "STRING  ÁÂÃÀÇÉÊÍÓÔÕÚ"
```

Answer (score 8):

The `.swapcase` method transforms the uppercase letters in a string to lowercase and the lowercase letters to uppercase.

```
'TESTING'.swapcase #=> testing
'testing'.swapcase #=> TESTING
```

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I was looking for. A mixed case string might make it more obvious exactly what this method does... `'Testing'.swapcase #=> tESTING`

Answer (score 2):

You can find strings method like `"strings".methods`
You can define string as `upcase`, `downcase`, `titleize`.
For Example,

```
"hii".downcase
"hii".titleize
"hii".upcase
```

Answer (score 1):

Since Ruby 2.4 there is a built in [full Unicode case mapping](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/v2_4_0_preview3/string.c#L6083-L6131). Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38016153/888294. See Ruby 2.4.0 documentation for details: https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/String.html#method-i-downcase

Answer (score 1):

Won't work for every, but this just saved me a bunch of time. I just had the problem with a CSV returning "TRUE or "FALSE" so I just added VALUE.to_s.downcase == "true" which will return the boolean true if the value is "TRUE" and false if the value is "FALSE", but will still work for the boolean true and false.

Answer (score 0):

In combination with `try` method, to support `nil` value:

```
'string'.try(:upcase)
'string'.try(:capitalize)
'string'.try(:titleize)
```