# Ruby 1.9: how can I properly upcase & downcase multibyte strings?

Tags: ruby, unicode, utf-8, internationalization, multibyte

So matz made the decision to keep `upcase` and `downcase` limited to `/[A-Z]/i` in ruby 1.9.1.

`ActiveSupport::Multibyte` has long had great i18n case jiggering in ruby 1.8.x via `String#mb_chars`.

However, when tried under ruby 1.9.1, it doesn't seem to work. Here's a simple test script I wrote, along with the output I'm getting:

```
$ cat test.rb
# encoding: UTF-8

puts("@ #{RUBY_VERSION} " + (__ENCODING__ rescue $KCODE).to_s)
sd, su = "Iñtërnâtiônàlizætiøn", "IÑTËRNÂTIÔNÀLIZÆTIØN"
def ps(u, d, k); puts "%-30s:  %24s / %-24s" % [k, u, d] end
ps sd.upcase, su.downcase, "Plain ruby"

require 'rubygems'; require 'active_support'
ps sd.upcase, su.downcase, "With active_support"
ps sd.mb_chars.upcase.to_s, su.mb_chars.downcase.to_s, "With active_support mb_chars"

$ ruby -KU test.rb
@ 1.8.7 UTF8
Plain ruby                    :  IñTëRNâTIôNàLIZæTIøN / iÑtËrnÂtiÔnÀlizÆtiØn
With active_support           :  IñTëRNâTIôNàLIZæTIøN / iÑtËrnÂtiÔnÀlizÆtiØn
With active_support mb_chars  :  IÑTËRNÂTIÔNÀLIZÆTIØN / iñtërnâtiônàlizætiøn

$ ruby1.9 test.rb
@ 1.9.1 UTF-8
Plain ruby                    :      IñTëRNâTIôNàLIZæTIøN / iÑtËrnÂtiÔnÀlizÆtiØn
With active_support           :      IñTëRNâTIôNàLIZæTIøN / iÑtËrnÂtiÔnÀlizÆtiØn
With active_support mb_chars  :      IñTëRNâTIôNàLIZæTIøN / iÑtËrnÂtiÔnÀlizÆtiØn
```

So, how do I get internationalized `upcase` and `downcase` with ruby 1.9.1?

#### update

I should add that I also tested with ActiveSupport from the current `master`, `2-3-*` and `3-0-unstable` rails branches at GitHub. Same results.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Case conversion is locale dependent and doesn't always round-trip, which is why Ruby 1.9 doesn't cover it (see [here](http://blade.nagaokaut.ac.jp/cgi-bin/scat.rb/ruby/ruby-core/19384) and [here](http://blade.nagaokaut.ac.jp/cgi-bin/scat.rb/ruby/ruby-core/26651))

The [unicode-util gem](https://github.com/lang/unicode_utils) should address your needs.

Comment: Cool, they even use the infamous capital turkish I with a dot in the README, which exemplifies the locale dependency you mention.

Answer (score 58):

for anybody coming from Google by `ruby upcase utf8`:

```
> "your problem chars here çöğıü Iñtërnâtiônàlizætiøn".mb_chars.upcase.to_s
=> "YOUR PROBLEM CHARS HERE ÇÖĞIÜ IÑTËRNÂTIÔNÀLIZÆTIØN"
```

solution is to use `mb_chars`.

Documentation:

- https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/activesupport/String#mb_chars-instance_method
- https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Multibyte/Chars.html

Comment: No, that is not the solution since case conversion is locale dependent. For example, `'ß'` would upcase to `'SS'` in a German locale but not a US locale.

Comment: Just the link to the ActiveSupport::Multibyte::Chars class: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Multibyte/Chars.html

Answer (score 14):

Case conversion is complicated and locale-dependent. Fortunately, Martin Dürst added [full Unicode case mapping](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/v2_4_0_preview3/string.c#L6083-L6131) in Ruby 2.4:

```
puts RUBY_DESCRIPTION

sd, su = "Iñtërnâtiônàlizætiøn", "IÑTËRNÂTIÔNÀLIZÆTIØN"
def ps(u, d, k); puts "%-30s:  %24s / %-24s" % [k, u, d] end 
ps sd.upcase,              su.downcase,              "Ruby 2.4 (default)"
ps sd.upcase(:ascii),      su.downcase(:ascii),      "Ruby 2.4 (ascii)"
ps sd.upcase(:turkic),     su.downcase(:turkic),     "Ruby 2.4 (turkic)"
ps sd.upcase(:lithuanian), su.downcase(:lithuanian), "Ruby 2.4 (lithuanian)"
ps "-",                    su.downcase(:fold),       "Ruby 2.4 (fold)"
```

Output:

```
ruby 2.4.0dev (2016-06-24 trunk 55499) [x86_64-linux]
Ruby 2.4 (default)            :      IÑTËRNÂTIÔNÀLIZÆTIØN / iñtërnâtiônàlizætiøn
Ruby 2.4 (ascii)              :      IñTëRNâTIôNàLIZæTIøN / iÑtËrnÂtiÔnÀlizÆtiØn
Ruby 2.4 (turkic)             :      IÑTËRNÂTİÔNÀLİZÆTİØN / ıñtërnâtıônàlızætıøn
Ruby 2.4 (lithuanian)         :      IÑTËRNÂTIÔNÀLIZÆTIØN / iñtërnâtiônàlizætiøn
Ruby 2.4 (fold)               :                         - / iñtërnâtiônàlizætiøn
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just wanna display the strings in uppercase in HTML, [CSS text-transform](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-transform) could be a better solution:

```
text-transform: uppercase
```