# Does Ruby share PHP's multibyte string problem?

Tags: php, ruby, string

PHP has a lot of trouble with multibyte strings (non-ASCII characters). The entire language was built assuming that each character is a byte. To solve this they invented the mb_strings functions which you can use instead of the standard functions (which work fine).

```
strlen($str);
mb_strlen($str); // correct
```

However, this is really a pain since you have to verify that the code you download/find online uses these functions or enable the `mb_string_overload` which then might break some code that actually needs `char = byte` calculations.

Does Ruby share this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think Ruby 1.9 clears up this underlaying assumption

Comment: How so? Can you expand on that thought?

Comment: http://blog.grayproductions.net/articles/ruby_19s_string documents how strings are different in Ruby 1.9

Answer (score 5):

It shares the problem. It's covered here at [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1910573/ruby-1-9-how-to-properly-upcase-downcase-multibyte-strings). You can use `ActiveSupport::Multibyte` for `mb_chars` support.

```
>> s =  "Iñtërnâtiônàlizætiøn"
=> "Iñtërnâtiônàlizætiøn"
>> puts s[0..3]
Iñt
=> nil
>> puts s.mb_chars[0..3]
Iñtë
=> nil
>> puts s.mb_chars.size
20
=> nil
>> puts s.size
27
=> nil
```

Answer (score 1):

```
irb(main):002:0> 'ÿ'.length
=> 2
```