# Capitalize only first character of string and leave others alone? (Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, string, capitalization

I'm trying to get Rails to capitalize the first character of a string, and leave all the others the way they are. I'm running into a problem where "i'm from New York" gets turned into "I'm from new york."

What method would I use to select the first character?

Thanks

**EDIT:** I tried to implement what macek suggested, but I'm getting a *"undefined method `capitalize'"* error. The code works fine without the capitalize line. Thanks for the help!

```
def fixlistname!
  self.title = self.title.lstrip + (title.ends_with?("...") ? "" : "...")
  self.title[0] = self.title[0].capitalize
  errors.add_to_base("Title must start with \"You know you...\"") unless self.title.starts_with? 'You know you'
end
```

**EDIT 2:** Got it working. Thanks for the help!

**EDIT 3:** Wait, no I didn't... Here's what I have in my list model.

```
def fixlistname!
  self.title = self.title.lstrip + (title.ends_with?("...") ? "" : "...")
  self.title.slice(0,1).capitalize + self.title.slice(1..-1)
  errors.add_to_base("Title must start with \"You know you...\"") unless self.title.starts_with?  'You know you'
end
```

**EDIT 4:** Tried macek's edit, and still getting an *undefined method `capitalize'"* error. What could I be doing wrong?

```
def fixlistname!
  self.title = title.lstrip
  self.title += '...' unless title.ends_with?('...')
  self.title[0] = title[0].capitalize
  errors.add_to_base('Title must start with "You know you..."') unless title.starts_with?("You know you")
end
```

**EDIT 5:** This is weird. I'm able to get rid of the undefined method error by using the line below. The problem is that it seems to replace the first letter with a number. For example, instead of capitalizing the *y* in *You*, it turns the *y* into a 121

```
self.title[0] = title[0].to_s.capitalize
```

Comment: Based on `EDIT 3`, you need to start line 2 with `self.title = `. Also, on all 3 lines, you only need `self.title` on the left of an `=` (equal sign). In other places you can just use `title`. See the edit on my answer for an example.

Comment: The problem in Edit4 is that you've got just a character - no longer a string - therefore it won't recognise the string-function "capitalize".

Comment: Problem with Edit 5 is that title[0] is a fixnum, so calling title[0].to_s will just give you the character number (i.e 121 as a string: "121").  You can do self.title[0] = title.first.capitalize if you want!

Comment: I added a #upcase_first_case and made a pull request: https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/15319. Feel free to add your feedback there.

Comment: Props to [`upcase_first`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2646709/capitalize-only-first-character-of-string-and-leave-others-alone-rails#answer-37336619) < answer there for anyone using Rails 5+. Credit @user1519240. Would be a good accepted answer if @DanielOConnor ever revisits this :)

Answer (score 96, accepted):

Titleize will capitalise every word.
This line feels hefty, but will guarantee that the only letter changed is the first one.

```
new_string = string.slice(0,1).capitalize + string.slice(1..-1)
```

Update:

```
irb(main):001:0> string = "i'm from New York..."
=> "i'm from New York..."
irb(main):002:0> new_string = string.slice(0,1).capitalize + string.slice(1..-1)
=> "I'm from New York..."
```

Comment: Wait, still not working. False alarm :/
I think I'm just implementing it wrong.

Comment: Daniel - it's generally good form to "accept" an answer that solved your problem. You can do this by clicking the "tick" to the left of the answer. :)

Comment: I misunderstood the question, otherwise I wanted to give you a 1 up. I was looking for .titleize instead of .capitalize. Thank you anyway Taryn!

Comment: OOC - Why does that stop you from giving an upvote? Did I correctly answer the original poster's question? If you think so - then upvote. It doesn't have to be dependent on anything else... :)

Comment: Suboptimal.  This fails if string is empty.

Comment: so, stick "if string.present?" on the end... not hard

Comment: So, here it goes: 

`s[0].capitalize + s[1..-1] if s.present?`

Answer (score 133):

This should do it:

```
title = "test test"     
title[0] = title[0].capitalize
puts title # "Test test"
```

Comment: @JonGarvin title[0].capitalize doesn't work (at least with Ruby 1.8.7), as title[0] returns a Fixnum, and capitalize expects a string.. so I think title.first.capitalize is the way to go.

Comment: shame you can't `title.first.capitalize!`

Comment: `capitalize` converts all letters after the first letter to lowercase, so it dosn't work for the string presented in the question ("i'm from New York").

Comment: Sorry I know this is old but thought I'd respond. We are only calling capitalize on the first character here, not the whole string, so it does work.

Comment: More shorter, `title[0] = title[0].upcase`

Answer (score 69):

As of [Rails 5.0.0.beta4](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/5-0-stable/activesupport/CHANGELOG.md#rails-500beta4-april-27-2016) you can use the new `String#upcase_first`method or `ActiveSupport::Inflector#upcase_first` to do it. Check this [blog post](https://glaucocustodio.github.io/2016/05/19/rails-5-new-upcase-first-method/) for more info.

So

```
"i'm from New York...".upcase_first
```

Will output:

```
"I'm from New York..."
```

Comment: Thats great news! I was thinking what we can do right now and maybe a polyfill for Rails 4 would be nice.

Comment: Note that upcase_first and doesn't handle accents/special chars, even with mb_chars

Answer (score 63):

You can use humanize.
If you don't need underscores or other capitals in your text lines.

Input:

```
"i'm from New_York...".humanize
```

Output:

```
"I'm from new york..."
```

Comment: The OP specifically wanted to avoid 'new york'

Comment: Hmm indeed, little bit too fast with my answer.

Comment: @Bartuzz Even though this isn't what OP wanted, this is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: new york however would be ungrammatical as its a proper noun and should use capitals.

Comment: Be warned, `humanize` is the Rails, exactly ActiveSupport method. Plain ruby can not do that.

Answer (score 59):

```
str = "this is a Test"
str.sub(/^./, &:upcase)
# => "This is a Test"
```

Comment: Concise and elegant. I believe this should be the top answer.

Comment: I agree. I think this should be the accepted answer.

Comment: One quirk is that since `^` means beginning of line, `"\nfoo"` becomes `"\nFoo"`. That's probably fine for most use cases. Since it's a `sub` and not a `gsub`, it will still only upcase one letter, even with multiline strings.

Comment: Can get the limitation above by using `str.sub(/\S/, &:upcase)`, which will find the first non-whitespace character and upcase it.

Answer (score 14):

An object oriented solution:

```
class String
  def capitalize_first_char
    self.sub(/^(.)/) { $1.capitalize }
  end
end
```

Then you can just do this:

```
"i'm from New York".capitalize_first_char
```

Comment: At least somebody wrote elegant solution with extending of `String` class.

Comment: @Dmitriy why is monkey patching the string class elegant?

Answer (score 8):

```
str.sub(/./, &:capitalize)
```

Answer (score 6):

### Edit 2

I can't seem to replicate your trouble. Go ahead and run this native Ruby script. It generates the exact output your looking for, and Rails supports all of these methods. What sort of inputs are you having trouble with?

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby
def fixlistname(title)
  title = title.lstrip
  title += '...' unless title =~ /\.{3}$/
  title[0] = title[0].capitalize
  raise 'Title must start with "You know you..."' unless title =~ /^You know you/
  title
end

DATA.each do |title|
  puts fixlistname(title)
end

__END__
you know you something WITH dots ...
you know you something WITHOUT the dots
  you know you something with LEADING whitespace...
  you know you something with whitespace BUT NO DOTS
this generates error because it doesn't start with you know you
```

#### output

```
You know you something WITH dots ...
You know you something WITHOUT the dots...
You know you something with LEADING whitespace...
You know you something with whitespace BUT NO DOTS...
RuntimeError: Title must start with "You know you..."
```

---

### Edit

Based on your edit, you can try something like this.

```
def fixlistname!
  self.title = title.lstrip
  self.title += '...' unless title.ends_with?('...')
  self.title[0] = title[0].capitalize
  errors.add_to_base('Title must start with "You know you..."') unless title.starts_with?("You know you")
end
```

---

### Original

This will do the trick

```
s = "i'm from New York"
s[0] = s[0].capitalize
#=> I'm from New York
```

---

When trying to use [`String#capitalize`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/String.html#M000795) on the whole string, you were seeing `I'm from new york` because the method:

> Returns a copy of *str* with the first character converted to uppercase and the remainder to lowercase.

```
"hello".capitalize    #=> "Hello"
"HELLO".capitalize    #=> "Hello"
"123ABC".capitalize   #=> "123abc"
```

Comment: +1 cause I didn't think that would work till I tried it on my pc :)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help. What am I doing wrong though? I've edited the original question to include my code.

Comment: I used Taryn's suggestion and got it working. Thanks for the help though!

Comment: Hi, stackoverflow says you made an edit, but I don't see anything different?

Answer (score 6):

```rb
my_string = "hello, World"
my_string.sub(/\S/, &:upcase) # => "Hello, World"
```

Comment: Does not fail if my_string is empty! Nice.  This is what I need.

Answer (score 3):

No-one's mentioned gsub, which lets you do this concisely.

```
string.gsub(/^([a-z])/) { $1.capitalize }
```

Example:

```
 > 'caps lock must go'.gsub(/^(.)/) { $1.capitalize }
=> "Caps lock must go"
```

Answer (score 3):

Most of these answers edit the string in place, when you are just formatting for view output you may not want to be changing the underlying string so you can use `tap` after a `dup` to get an edited copy

```
'test'.dup.tap { |string| string[0] = string[0].upcase }
```

Answer (score 3):

If and only if OP would want to do monkey patching on String object, then this can be used

```
class String
  # Only capitalize first letter of a string
  def capitalize_first
    self.sub(/\S/, &:upcase)
  end
end
```

Now use it:

```
"i live in New York".capitalize_first #=> I live in New York
```

Answer (score 2):

An even shorter version could be:

```
s = "i'm from New York..."
s[0] = s.capitalize[0]
```

Answer (score 1):

Note that if you need to deal with multi-byte characters, i.e. if you have to internationalize your site, the `s[0] = ...` solution won't be adequate.  This Stack Overflow question suggests using the [unicode-util gem](https://github.com/lang/unicode_utils)

[Ruby 1.9: how can I properly upcase & downcase multibyte strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1910573/ruby-1-9-how-to-properly-upcase-downcase-multibyte-strings)

**EDIT**

Actually an easier way to at least avoid strange string encodings is to just use [String#mb_chars](http://apidock.com/rails/String/mb_chars):

```
s = s.mb_chars
s[0] = s.first.upcase
s.to_s
```

Answer (score 1):

Rails starting from version 5.2.3 has [upcase_first](https://apidock.com/rails/v5.2.3/String/upcase_first) method.

For example, `"my Test string".upcase_first` will return `My Test string`.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the easiest way.

```
s = "test string"
s[0] = s[0].upcase
# => "Test string"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
"i'm from New York".camelize
=> "I'm from New York"
```

Comment: While this may work, from a semantic point-of-view, I'm not sure that `camelize` tells me that it will capitalize the first character. In C# world, for example, we call capitalizing the first word "Pascal case," and lower case first word "camel case."

Comment: This is not the same: `i'm from New York C_1".camelize` => "I'm from New York C1", the "_" has disapeared

Answer (score -3):

```
string = "i'm from New York"
string.split(/\s+/).each{ |word,i| word.capitalize! unless i > 0 }.join(' ')
# => I'm from New York
```

Comment: Seems so. I'm new to ruby, and the other answers didn't actually do what the OP asked, so I made it work :D

Correct me if I'm wrong, but AFAIK modifying a string by changing string[i] doesn't work in a lot of languages?

Comment: this is a Ruby-specific question. It doesn't matter if `string[i]` doesn't work in other languages. Please help keep StackOverflow clutter-free of these kind of hacked-up answers. We can't say RTFM, but even a *quick* glance at the `String` docs would've helped avoid an answer like this...