# Rails: How to downcase non-English string?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, string, ruby-on-rails-3, lowercase

How could I downcase a non-English string in Ruby on Rails 3 ?

```
str = "Привет"    # Russian 
puts str[0].ord   # => 1055
str.downcase!
puts str[0].ord   # => 1055 (Should be 1087)
```

I want it to work in Ruby 1.8.7 as well as Ruby 1.9.2.

Comment: You mean a greek one or any kind of non-english one ?

Comment: Currently, I'm interested in the Russian language, but I may want to use other languages in future, so I'm looking for a general solution.

Answer (score 97, accepted):

```
str = "Привет"
str.mb_chars.downcase.to_s
#=> "привет"
```

Comment: Without rails you need an aditional `require 'active_support/core_ext'` to avoid an _undefined method_-error

Comment: awesome why they didn't fix it in ruby 2.0 :(

Comment: `mb_chars` also works with `capitalize` and `upcase`. Great solution!
We also can call `'Привет'.mb_chars.downcase.wrapped_string`

Comment: In Ruby 2.4 it finally works as expected: `"Привет".downcase
#=> "привет"`

Answer (score 7):

Why not to use gem `unicode_utils`. This gem will not force `downcase` to work, however you can use:

```
UnicodeUtils.downcase('Привет') #=> 'привет'
```

Answer (score 6):

If you want to use it easy like this:

```
> "Привет".downcase
=> "привет"
```

you have to put into initializers folder file **string.rb**

```
require 'unicode'

class String
  def downcase
    Unicode::downcase(self)
  end
  def downcase!
    self.replace downcase
  end
  def upcase
    Unicode::upcase(self)
  end
  def upcase!
    self.replace upcase
  end
  def capitalize
    Unicode::capitalize(self)
  end
  def capitalize!
    self.replace capitalize
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Since Ruby 2.4 there is a built in [full Unicode case mapping](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/v2_4_0_preview3/string.c#L6083-L6131). Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38016153/888294. See Ruby 2.4.0 documentation for details: https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/String.html#method-i-downcase

Answer (score 1):

A nice and easy solution in rails is to add string.rb into initializers folder, then in this file you can override String using mb_chars, now downcase support accents and letters like Ñ

```
class String
  def downcase
    self.mb_chars.downcase.to_s
  end

  def capitalize
    self.mb_chars.capitalize.to_s
  end

  def upcase
    self.mb_chars.upcase.to_s
  end

  def titleize
    self.mb_chars.titleize.to_s
  end
end
```