# Comparing utf-8 string that have different byte in special characters

Tags: ruby, string, character-encoding

SomeObject.find(20).client.full_name.downcase.bytes.each{|b| puts b}

- 98 197 130 97 197 188 101 106 101 119 115

=> "błażejewsk"
 OtherClass.find(36).client.downcase.bytes.each {|b| puts b}

- 98 197 129 97 197 187 101 106 101 119 115

=> "bŁaŻejewsk"

As you can see special characters have different bytes in both string . 
Both string have Encoding:UTF-8, so force_encoding or something like that , wouldn't help. == returns false. How should I convert those string so I can get true from comparison?

Comment: I don't get it, what you are tring to avoid?

Comment: please try to improve the quality of your post. What is the question ?

Comment: @toro2k My guess that *130* and *129*..

Comment: It's probably about case-insensitive string comparison in Unicode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will not work with `downcase` see http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/String.html#method-i-downcase-21

> Returns a copy of str with all uppercase letters replaced with their lowercase counterparts. The operation is locale insensitive—only characters “A” to “Z” are affected. Note: case replacement is effective only in ASCII region.

See this question to properly downcase UTF-8 strings [Ruby 1.9: how can I properly upcase & downcase multibyte strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1910573/ruby-1-9-how-can-i-properly-upcase-downcase-multibyte-strings)

Comment: I will try gem from link given in post u pasted. For now i just made it by comparing string without all non-ascii digits.