# In Ruby, how do I find the index of an element in an array in a case-insensitive way?

Tags: arrays, ruby, indexof, case-insensitive

I’m using Ruby 2.3.  I’m able to find the index of an element in an array using

```
2.3.0 :001 > a = ["A", "B", "C"]
 => ["A", "B", "C"] 
2.3.0 :003 > a.index("B")
 => 1
```

but how would I do it if I wanted to find the index of the element in a case-insensitive way?  E.g., I could do

```
2.3.0 :003 > a.index(“b”)
```

and get the same result as above?  You can assume that if all the elements were upper-cased, there won’t be two of the same element in the array.

Comment: In your example, could you have `a = ["A", "B", "C", "b"]`? If so, what to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`Array#find_index`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Array.html#method-i-find_index):

```
a = ["A", "B", "C"]
a.find_index {|item| item.casecmp("b") == 0 }
# or
a.find_index {|item| item.downcase == "b" }
```

Note that the usual Ruby caveats apply for case conversion and comparison of accented and other non-[Latin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_basic_Latin_alphabet) characters. This will change in Ruby 2.4. See this SO question: [Ruby 1.9: how can I properly upcase & downcase multibyte strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1910573/ruby-1-9-how-can-i-properly-upcase-downcase-multibyte-strings)

Answer (score 0):

If you know the string contains all upper case letters, you can use the method `upcase` to convert the string to uppercase as such:

```
2.3.0 :001 > a = ["A", "B", "C"]
 => ["A", "B", "C"] 
2.3.0 :002 > a.index("b".upcase)
 => 1 
2.3.0 :003 > tmp = "c"
 => "c" 
2.3.0 :004 > a.index(tmp.upcase)
 => 2
```

Comment: You are assuming all the elements in my array are upper case, which is not true.  What I put in the question is just an example.

Comment: `"b".upcase` can be replaced by `"B"`.