# How to convert case of French Characters

Tags: ruby, unicode

I have to convert case in `Québec` to `QUÉBEC`, but am unable to do so. Can someone please guide me? In my spec file, I included:

```
require 'unicode_utils/upcase'
```

and then I did:

```
p UnicodeUtils.upcase("Québec", :fr)
```

and got the following Argument error at run time:

```
wrong number of arguments (0 or 1+)
```

I even tried passing `nil` as the second argument, but got the same error. What am I missing? I got some reference from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1020568/how-does-one-convert-a-string-to-lowercase-in-ruby).

```
$ gem install unicode_utils
$ irb
> require 'unicode_utils'  
=> true  
> UnicodeUtils.downcase("FEN BİLİMLERİ", :tr)  
=> "fen bilimleri"
```

Comment: It works for me. I posted an answer assuming your require is what's wrong, but that's not it either. Does your error message definitely refer to the line as you have posted it? The `.upcase` method in v1.4.0 takes two params, not `1+`

Comment: yes, it says"Failure/Error: p UnicodeUtils.upcase("Québec", :fr)   Argument Error: Wrong number of arguments (0 or 1+)" .... Is is something that needs to be installed inaddition to the unicode_utils gem?

Comment: Is the second argument ":fr" correct?

Comment: Works also for me. D you use the actual version of [unicode_utils](http://rubygems.org/gems/unicode_utils) (1.4.0)?

Comment: yes, i did.    another observation: when in the console I copy the line UnicodeUtils.upcase("Québec", :fr); instead the following gets copied:  UnicodeUtils.upcase("Qu\U+FF3\U+FFA9bec", :fr) and hitting Enter returns "QUBEC" (with the missing accented É after U)..  any idea what this string refers to?

Comment: That's cut&paste mis-behaving, and not anything wrong with your test. I get the same error if I cut&paste from the question to IRB on my Mac. When I say "It works for me", I mean that I have used your code from the question as-is, and I get the output `"QUÉBEC"` The argument `:fr` is correct. Could you confirm your file encoding, and that you are using correct Ruby encoding at top of file - e.g. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8879237/how-does-the-magic-comment-encoding-utf-8-in-ruby-works

Comment: Thanks much Neil!   Yes, it does work for me too now.  Actually, I'm using calabash-ios and rspec framework for automating our ios app testing. In my spec file, I do require 'spec_helper' and require 'calabash-cucumber'. When I was running the above example, i was getting the Wrong number of Arguments. However, when I commented the line "require 'spec_helper'", I did get the correct case conversion output: "QUÉBEC". Quite strange!!  Not sure if there is another upcase() methods defined anywhere inaddition to UnicodeUtils.upcase.rb. WHen I go to the declaration, It just shows one upcase method

Comment: any thoughts for how can I confirm this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use

`"Québec".mb_chars.upcase` => QUÉBEC

for non-ASCII characters.

Thanks.